# MongoDB: 'If not exists, then create' ACID compliance

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, promise, bluebird, acid

I am working on an application which has a routine similar to the code below:

```
//The model in question is used as a bugtracker, where all caught errors 
//are collected together inside a bug-object with a unique code to track
//which function threw it

createOrUpdateBug: function(functionIdentifier, thrownError) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Promise.try(function() {
      return model.findOne({bugCode: functionIdentifier})
    }.then(function(foundModel) {
      if (foundModel) {
        foundModel.errors.push(thrownError)
        return foundModel.save()
      } else {
        var newModel = new Model()
        newModel.errors.push(thrownError)
        return newModel.save()
      }
    }.then(function(savedModel) {
      resolve(savedModel)
    }) //.catch with reject omitted
  })
}
```

I have read up on MongoDB, and it seems that it is not ACID compliant, or at least not for *updating and saving multiple documents*. From what I understand, this means that when 2 documents are affected by an action, and they are both saved asynchronously, at some point they will become inconsistent in respect to each other due to possible server anomalies. Is this somewhat correct?

In my case, I would like to guarantee that there will only be 1 document per functionIdentifier. However, if this function is ran concurrently, could it not be possible that it would generate multiple documents with the same functionIdentifier like so?

[1] See if model exists -> [2] See if model exists -> [1] No model Found -> [2] No model found -> [1] Create model -> [2] Create model -> [1] Save model -> [2] Save model

I could mark the functionIdentifier as unique in the DB, but then wont I lose the information from the second process when the validation is violated?

MongoDB is supposed to be ACID compliant on the document level, but I'm not sure if this safeguards my implementation above. Or does it?

Comment: Yes, your scenario would be possible, each operation in itself is ACID(ish), however doing multiple operations in sequence does not guarantee that they all complete in an ACID manner. What you're looking for may be an [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option).

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely want is an `upsert` which inserts or updates a document depending on whether it exists:

```
// Push an error to bugcode 1
db.model.update({bugCode:1}, {$push: {'errors' : 'error 1'}}, {upsert:1})

// Push an error to bugcode 1
db.model.update({bugCode:1}, {$push: {'errors' : 'error 2'}}, {upsert:1})

// Push an error to bugcode 2
db.model.update({bugCode:2}, {$push: {'errors' : 'error 3'}}, {upsert:1})

db.model.find()

// { "_id" : ObjectId("56c88be6604725e791ffd967"), 
//    "bugCode" : 1, "errors" : [ "error 1", "error 2" ] }  // Two errors

// { "_id" : ObjectId("56c88c09fc04922eb90fcc61"), 
//    "bugCode" : 2, "errors" : [ "error 3" ] }             // One error
```

Answer (score 0):

> MongoDB is supposed to be ACID compliant on the document level, but I'm not sure if this safeguards my implementation above. Or does it?

It doesn't in the scenario you've stated yourself. However, if your functionIdentifier is meant to be unique, you can set it as the `_id` field and it will trigger an automatic "if does exist, update, else insert" behavior from the `save`.

See the [save documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db.collection.save).